# MySQL WHERE IN (SELECT id from ...) fastest approach?

Tags: php, mysql, database, performance

I am using a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM videos WHERE id IN (SELECT video_id FROM videos_tags WHERE tag_id = 2)
```

to search videos with the same tags, but with about 8'000 videos this query is too slow. How can I make this query faster? Maybe a JOIN is faster? Something like select * from videos_tags left join videos on (videos_tags.video_id = videos.id) where videos_tags.tag_id = 2 is faster?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can alternative use `JOIN` instead of subquery.

```
SELECT  DISTINCT a.*
FROM    videos a
        INNER JOIN video_tags b
            ON a.ID = b.video_ID
WHERE   b.tag_id = 2
```

For faster performance, create a foreign key constraint on `video_tags` table which references on `videos`. Example, (*make sure that `video.ID` is a Primary Key or a Unique Key*)

```
ALTER TABLE video_tags ADD CONSTRAINT vt_fk 
            FOREIGN KEY (video_ID) REFERENCES video(ID)
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: Thank you! :D I tried to run `ALTER TABLE videos_tags ADD CONSTRAINT vt_fk FOREIGN KEY (video_id) REFERENCES videos(id)`, but it fails saying: ``Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mytube`.`#sql-22cd_151980`, CONSTRAINT `vt_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`video_id`) REFERENCES `videos` (`id`))`` Ahn, videos.id is Primary key auto increment. :/

Comment: because your table has already records. much better if you can delete all the records first or just the one that `video_id` doesn't exists on `video.id`.

Comment: Uh, found it using SELECT * FROM videos_tags LEFT OUTER JOIN videos ON (videos_tags.video_id = videos.id) and finding for NULL :) Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 2):

What version of MySQL are you using?  The problem with the optimization of `in` seems to be fixed in version 5.6.

I think the fastest version otherwise is to use `exists`:

```
SELECT *
FROM videos
WHERE exists (SELECT 1
              FROM videos_tags
              WHERE video_tags.tag_id = 2 and video_tags.video_id = videos.id
             )
```

This version also has the benefit that you do not run into the possibility of multiple matches (in the tags table) resulting in multiple identical rows.  This would happen, for instance, if you changed the query to look for tags 2 and 3, and some videos had both.

For optimal performance, have an index on `videos_tags(tag_id, video_id)`.

Comment: +1 for the `EXISTS`, +1 for the useful index, +1 for the info about 5.6 optimizer. Damn, I can only +1 once.